# After calling update function in SQLite db, the data is not updated and returns 0 value

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, sqliteopenhelper

I'm trying to create a function which will update the password in the database. The function itself returns true value, however the data is not updated and remains the same. Also I changed the result of that long value and it returns 0. I'll very grateful for some suggestions on how to make it work correctly. Here's the code of the function:

```
public Boolean changePassword(String name, String email, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("email", email);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("Select * from UserDetails where name = ? and email = ?", new String [] {name,email});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            long result = DB.update("UserDetails", contentValues, "password = ?", new String[] { password });

            System.out.println("Result= "+result);

            if (result == -1)
                return false;
             else
                return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: The method update() never returns -1. Change to: `if (result == 0)`.

Comment: yeah it does return 0, but I don't understand how to fix it

Comment: Fix what? If there is no row in the table with that name an email then nothing will be updated.